# Problema al reducir la pantalla en html

Tags: html, css

Continúo con mi aprendizaje en html y tengo algunos problemas. El caso es que estoy haciendo un html y tengo una imagen, pero cuando reduzco la pantalla la imagen se reduce demasiado y no se centra. El problema está en que no encuentro el por qué.

```
/*Div de quienessomosimg*/ .foto {width: 30%;height: 500px; margin: 10px auto; margin-left: 65px; overflow: hidden; float: left;} img {width: 100%; height: auto;}

<div class="foto">
  <img src="vista-vertical-torre-eiffel-paris-francia_1258-3169.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Si pudieran ayudarme les estaría muy agradecido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu imagen se hace pequeña porque has establecido 30% como tamaño, por ende mantiene ese tamaño en proporción al tamaño de la pantalla, para editar esa instruccion puedes usar media querys, las cuales son instrucciones que se pueden dar a un elemento dependiendo del tamaño de pantalla, por ejemplo:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.foto {
     width: 70%;
   }
}
```

Esto cambia el tamaño de 30% por un 70% al llegar a un tamaño de pantalla de 800px, toma en cuenta que estas usando un alto estático, mi recomendación es que uses un `height: auto;` para no tener que estar calculando el alto de la imagen en cada query

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ha funcionado a la perfección ;)